# Google Cloud Ingress returning 404 for externalName

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

trying to setup my GC Kubernetes. Using the Ingress controller for the load balancing. While it works perfect for services connected to containers running on my kubernetes, I struggle to get it working for my external wordpress.

I followed the explaination on https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/ and created a service without selector.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: external-wordpress-service
    annotations: 
        ingress.kubernetes.io/preserve-host: "false"
spec:
    type: ExternalName
    externalName: xyz.myraidbox.de
```

Then I edit my ingress.yaml to point to this service

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: spx-ingress
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - domain.com
    - www.domain.com
    secretName: le-tls-cert-prod-04
  backend:
    serviceName: frontend-service
    servicePort: 80
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: frontend-service
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /test/
        backend:
          serviceName: external-wordpress-service
          servicePort: 80
```

So the plan is to have to have www.domain.com/test/ to access my external wordpress on the root level

www.domain.com/test/ -> xyz.myraidbox.de

After almost a billion edits I still get the 404 and my frontend returns the 404 page instead of contents from my external WP.

Any suggestions? Thx in advance

Cheers Andy

Answer (score 1):

I see that the Ingress backend is not configured to point to a kubernetes resource, but it points to an external website (wordpress). This is possible, you can create a backend that points to an external website in the `Service`, however, you would need to add more specifications to the `Service`.

Solution : Try to follow this example in [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/pull/629#issue-116679227), and specify a `port` 80, a `targetport` and a `protocol` in the `Service`.

In the following way:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: external-wordpress-service
  annotations: 
        ingress.kubernetes.io/preserve-host: "false"
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: xyz.myraidbox.de
```